# LIMIT in SQL Server Express database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to limit to only 10 results, something like below.

I have searched online but cannot find a solution.

```
SELECT [Id], [Name], [Age], [Date], [Time] 
FROM [People] 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: SELECT TOP 10 columnName1,columnName2, ... From table

Comment: why you tagged it with asp-classic?

Answer (score 4):

No you haven't searched . Anyways here it is

```
SELECT TOP 10  [Id], [Name], [Age], [Date], [Time] FROM [People]
```

Note : 
Without `ORDER BY` clause , this will give random 10 records

Comment: +1 : `random` => `arbitrary`.  They could be the same 10 every time, based on Clustered Index.  Or they might not.  There are just no *guarantees* as to which you get, even if it *appears* that it's reliable most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

`LIMIT` is a [MySQL Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp).

T-SQL has [`TOP` DML Statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) for that.

> Limits the rows returned in a query result set to a specified number
>   of rows or percentage of rows in SQL Server 2012. When TOP is used in
>   conjunction with the ORDER BY clause, the result set is limited to the
>   first N number of ordered rows; **otherwise, it returns the first N
>   number of rows in an undefined order.**

```
SELECT TOP 10 [Id], [Name], [Age], [Date], [Time]
FROM [People]
ORDER BY [Id]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
SELECT TOP 10 [Id], [Name], [Age], [Date], [Time] 
FROM [People]
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 10 [Id], [Name], [Age], [Date], [Time] 
FROM [People] 
ORDER BY [Id] DESC  -- Descending Order View
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

SELECT TOP 10 [Id], [Name], [Age], [Date], [Time] 
FROM [People]

now it depends on you in which order you want i mean

SELECT TOP 10 [Id], [Name], [Age], [Date], [Time] 
FROM [People] order by Asc or desc